# How to stop onLocationResult() in Service Class?

Tags: android, locationlistener, google-location-services

I have a service class which will get the user's location from 9:00 am to 18:00 pm. I am using alarm Manager to trigger the `selfStop();` which is in the broadcast receiver like

**Alarm Manager:**

```
 public void StopTracking() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, StopTime);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, StopMin);


        String stop = "stop";
        registerReceiver(stopReceiver, new IntentFilter(stop));

        if (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, new Intent(stop), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Pending Intent Started");
            PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 0, new Intent(stop), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            assert alarmManager != null;
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), broadcastIntent);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "StopTracking: Pending Intent Stoped!");
        }
    }

    protected BroadcastReceiver stopReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "received stop broadcast");
            // Stop the service when the notification is tapped

            unregisterReceiver(stopReceiver);
            stopSelf();

            intent = new Intent(context, StopService.class);
            context.startService(intent);
        }
    };
```

but i am unable to stop the location function in the same service class
bellow is my location function

**Location Function:**

```
private void requestLocationUpdates() {

    request.setInterval(10000);
    request.setFastestInterval(5000);
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    final String path = getString(R.string.firebase_path) + "/" + getString(R.string.transport_id);
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Request location updates and when an update is
        // received, store the location in Firebase
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path);
                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                if (location != null) {
                    ref.setValue(location);
                    Toast.makeText(TrackerService.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String lattitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                    String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

                    Save_LocationOffline(lattitude, longitude);
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

This is my Problem,

The broadcast receiver works and i i have triggered the `selfStop();` and `OnDestroy` part worked, **but location function is still working and not stopped**.

Can any one explain what is the problem. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using the google play service for location in order to retrieve the location.

If you check the [FusedLocationProviderClient documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html), they said that when you use `requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest, LocationCallback, Looper)`, you should call `removeLocationUpdates(LocationCallback)`.

You first need to extract the location callback, for example like this:

```
 class MyService .... {
    // Member into your service
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {...}

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        ...
         client.requestLocationUpdates(request, mLocationCallback, null)
        ...
    }

    // Into you stopReceiver
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
        client.removeLocationUpdate(mLocationCallback )
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i am using google play service for live asset tracking at run time!

Comment: ok i dont need any call back cause i am not going to show to the user i need to remove the request update thats it

Comment: The callback is to receive the location. This is the same callback in the request/ removeLocationUpdate

Comment: This is what I did. I put the callback from client.updateLocationUpdate to inside the service, because you will need this callback to call  removeUpdateLocation